# unwanted column changing when updating table with Laravel Eloquent

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a cronjob in Laravel scheduled to update some info in a table once a day. That job just call a function and that function try to update the table. What is happening is that when the information is updated, the column `request_at` is updated with the same info as `updated_at`, but only the columns `updated_at` and `status_id` should be changed

Here's my model, the migration and the function called by the cronjob

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOne;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class StockRecharge extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $fillable = [
        'worker_stock_id',
        'status_id',
        'requested_at'
    ];

    protected $casts = [
        'worker_stock_id' => 'integer',
        'status_id' => 'integer',
        'requested_at' => 'datetime'
    ];

    /**
     * Return the related status 
     * @return HasOne
     */
    public function status(): HasOne
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Status::class);
    }

    /**
     * Return the related worker stock
     * @return BelongsTo
     */
    public function workerStock(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(WorkerStock::class);
    }
}
```

migration

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateStockRecharges extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('stock_recharges', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->foreignId('worker_stock_id')->constrained('worker_stocks')->cascadeOnDelete()->cascadeOnUpdate();
            $table->tinyInteger('status_id', false, true);
            $table->timestampTz('requested_at');
            $table->timestampsTz();
            $table->softDeletesTz();

            $table->foreign('status_id')->references('id')->on('statuses')->cascadeOnDelete()->cascadeOnUpdate();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('stock_recharges');
    }
}
```

cronjob

```
private static function updateStockRechargeToExpiring(): bool
    {
        Log::info('starting updateStockRechargeToExpiring()');

        try {
            StockRecharge::whereNull('deleted_at')
                ->where('status_id', StatusRepository::getByName('ACTIVE'))
                ->whereRaw('DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), requested_at) = 4')
                ->update(['status_id' => StatusRepository::getByName('EXPIRING')]);
        } catch (\Throwable) {
            Log::error('status update failed on updateStockRechargeToExpiring()');
            return false;
        }

        Log::info('job updateStockRechargeToExpiring() finished successfully');

        return true;
    }
```

I've used the the function `DB::enableQueryLog()` to see exactly what was the query and got the following:

```
array:2 [
  0 => array:3 [
    "query" => "select `id` from `statuses` where (`name` = ?)"
    "bindings" => array:1 [
      0 => "EXPIRING"
    ]
    "time" => 4.92
  ]
  1 => array:3 [
    "query" => "update `stock_recharges` set `status_id` = ?, `updated_at` = ? where `deleted_at` is null and DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), requested_at) = 4"
    "bindings" => array:2 [
      0 => 3
      1 => "2024-03-19 12:27:32"
    ]
    "time" => 0.76
  ]
]
```

As we can see, there's no mention of `request_at` in the query, but it is changed anyway.

I've tried using `DB::table('stock_recharges')` instead of the model `StockRecharge`, but the result was the same

Laravel 9.52
MySQL 8.0.31

Has anyone faced something like it before?

Comment: Can you show the `show create table` for that table in your database? It could be a mysql trigger

Comment: edited with the migration

Comment: mysql? and what version? also what version of Laravel?

Comment: edited with laravel and mysql version

Comment: I'm assuming it's an Eloquent issue. I did tried using `DB::statement("update stock_recharges set status_id = $newStatus, requested_at = requested_at, stock_recharges.updated_at = current_timestamp() where deleted_at is null and status_id = $currentStatus and DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), requested_at) = 4 and stock_recharges.deleted_at is null")` and it worked as expected, but since it doesn't address the source of the problem, I won't say it is a reliable solution

Comment: you might have an event that runs on model update or save and performs the second change, try wrapping your update query in `StockRecharge::withoutEvents(...)`

Comment: I don't use events or observers in this project, but I still tried this approach, yet the problem persisted

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
->whereRaw('DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), requested_at)', '=', '4')
```

I think it is a conflict because you defined `requesed_at` while you are searching with `whereRaw`

Comment: this won't work since `whereRaw()`'s second and third args are `$bindings = []`, `$boolean = 'and'`

Comment: Is that changes same with other variable?

Comment: yes, no matter the columns for update